pyautogui.typewrite не может писать кириллицей
Хотел написать простенький спамер (пока тока учусь програмированию), но бот вместо кириллици пишет пустоту, что можно сделать?
import pyautogui
import time

print("Запуск сделан!")

def SendMessage():
    message = input("Введите сообщение:")
    amount = 10000
    time.sleep(1)

    for i in range(amount):
        pass

    while amount > 0:
        amount -= 1

        pyautogui.typewrite (message.strip())
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(3)

SendMessage()


И как он должен работать?

И print ничего не выводит? Поверьте, какая кодировка у вашей программы для начала. Где-то там в углу обычно выбирается кодировка редактора

Вопрос никак не связан с PyCharm. По pyautogui.typewrite см. pyautogui.typewrite не работает русский
